# How to pivot table in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to pivot a table, but I am stuck because of reapeated **Action** values.
Goal: extract values from the **Action** column and use them as the headers for new columns. Then, fill the new table with values from the **Val** column. In this instance, there is only one group, so you can utilize a window function to capture all groups with ID column. All SN are unique, but other actions can be repeated for the same SN

I have a table:

| Val | Action | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SN1844Q | SN | 94a52150-a24f-11ed |
| 2000 | Check_X | 94a52150-a24f-11ed |
| 1 | Pass | 94a52150-a24f-11ed |
| 2022-01-12 23:51:31 | DateTime | 94a52150-a24f-11ed |
| up | Position | 94a52150-a24f-11ed |
| back | Position | 94a52150-a24f-11ed |
| 890 | Check_X | 94a52150-a24f-11ed |
| SN1845Q | SN | 28497a86-8e8e-44da |
| ... | ... | ... |

I want to see:

| SN | Check_X | Pass | DateTime | Position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SN1844Q | 2000 | 1 | 2022-01-12 23:51:31 | up |
| SN1844Q | 890 | 1 | 2022-01-12 23:51:31 | back |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: How do you know which action values that belong to a specific SN?

Comment: So, I work with SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS). There is another column (BatchId) with ids for each row in the example.

Comment: Add the id column too. It's more or less crucial.

Comment: That's not pivoting. You have a badly designed table according to the EAV antipattern (ie very bad design idea) and now try to convert it to a normal table form. In fact, without an explicit ID column, it's simply impossible to even guess which rows belong to the same "object".

Comment: Rows in database tables have no order, unless one is imposed by an `ORDER BY` clause. That means that *none* of the example's rows can be considered to belong to a specific serial number or have any relation to any other row. There's no reason to assume that `SN1844Q` and `2000` belong to the same row, or that `2000` and `890` should appear in different "rows"

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Where did this data come from and why is it in that shape? Whatever the actual problem is, there are far easier ways to solve it

Comment: The ID column was added to distinguish actions...

Comment: The table comes from different queries and I am trying to convert it into normal format.

Comment: Is there another column which maintains a proper sequence or at least the entity's group?

Comment: Only ID allows to highlight groups (SN-Actions). Within the group the order is already defined and it's possible to use ROW_NUMBER() to make the order.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use SQL pivot with a dynamic query [click here](https://www.sqlshack.com/dynamic-pivot-tables-in-sql-server/) .

Comment: Really easy documentation and dynamic , good !!!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SN,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Action = 'Action 1' THEN Val END) AS "Action 1",
       MAX(CASE WHEN Action = 'Action 2' THEN Val END) AS "Action 2",
       MAX(CASE WHEN Action = 'Action 3' THEN Val END) AS "Action 3"
FROM original_table
GROUP BY SN
```

In this query, the MAX function is used in the CASE statement to aggregate the values from the Val column, while the GROUP BY clause is used to group the results by the SN column. The CASE statement is used to match the values in the Action column and return the corresponding values from the Val column. The result of the query will be a new table with columns for each unique value in the Action column, with the values from the Val column filling in the appropriate cells

Comment: Your query does not take into account different values for the same action with MAX()